# Build a module with a task

Tags: gradle, build, build.gradle

I wanted to build a particular module from my project via a task, which will in turn run its tests. Basically I want to execute, "gradle :module:build" from a task.

```
task thatBuildsTheModule() << {
   .....
}

task A() << {
  ......
  tasks.thatBuidsTheModule.execute()
  ......
}
```

How can I do this ?

Answer (score 1):

You're close.  It's not recommended to call execute on a `task`.  Instead use the task graph and make your builder task a dependant of your `A` task, labeled `anotherTask` in this example

```
// create builder task
task thatBuildsTheModule << {
    println "Hello $it.name"
}
// create our other task
task anotherTask << {
    println "Hello $it.name"
}
// make `anotherTask`'s execution depend on the execution of our builder task
anotherTask.dependsOn thatBuildsTheModule
```

Now we can see that executing just the `anotherTask` task we also execute the `thatBuildsTheModule` task

```
$ ./gradlew -q anotherTask
Hello thatBuildsTheModule
Hello anotherTask
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!
Also, is there a way to build a module from a task ? How do I trigger a build from inside a task? (basically do "gradle :module:build" from a task)

Comment: You want to make the task dependant on the other task.   `project('module').tasks.findByName('build').dependsOn anotherTask` now executing `anotherTask` will execute `:module:build` also.

Comment: project('module').tasks.findByName('build').dependsOn is null. What could be the possible reasons ?

Comment: Depending on where your calling this from (example if called from a subproject) you might have to get the module from the `rootProject`.  Example: `project.rootProject.project('module').tasks.findByname('build').dependsOn anotherTask`

Comment: Thanks a lot! Also, can I configure the build task to a setting that runs the build and the tests in the fastest way possible? For example, a parrallel execution of operation, having more heap memory for tests, etc. Something like project.rootProject.project('module').tasks.findByname('build').configure?

Comment: Your task won't be able to affect the command line params.  However your plugin could try to be smart like only perform setup/IO if required and keeping logging to a minimum.  That's about all you can do to affect performance beyond good programming practices.  Also some projects might have issues with parallel execution if they are not expecting this behavior.

Comment: I did : project.rootProject.project('module').tasks.findByname('build').configure {
  setProperty('-Xmx', '5g')
}. And I think it worked.